# Which C# field creates an Azure Table Storage column as "binary" type

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

If you have `bool`, `int`, `string` or `Guid` types as members in your C# TableEntity class, these are converted to Azure Table columns with appropriate types.

It seems like an Azure Table column can be of types: `string`, `binary`, `bool`, `boolean`, `byte`, `datetime`, `decimal`, `double`, `guid`, `int`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `single`, `sbyte`.

Among those types, which type should I use in my C# class to generate an Azure table column as `binary` type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save binary to Azure Table Storage by TableServiceEntity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879373/how-to-save-binary-to-azure-table-storage-by-tableserviceentity)

Comment: yep, it is awesome it is not listed in Related Questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

byte[]

From [Understanding Table Service Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx).

Comment: LOL, I tried this before asking but my storage explorer was showing column "contents" as System.Byte[] and I thought "damn it just does .ToString() on type", but turned out that it actually stores the bytes. :) Thanks!